# Sqlite copy data from temp table to another with conflict

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

i have db sqlite with main table and temp table. I want to import data from text file and then i want to insert data from temp table to main table.

```
INSERT INTO table(key) SELECT src.key FROM temp as src
ON CONFLICT (table.key) DO UPDATE SET to_insert = 0, to_delete =0;
```

When i am trying run this query then sqlite throw me this error.

> Query 1 ERROR: near "DO": syntax error

Is possible insert data from another table with conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` statement needs a `where` clause:

```
insert into mytable(key) 
select key from temp where true
on conflict (key) do update set to_insert = 0, to_delete =0;
```

This pitfall is documented as [parsing ambiguity](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) (emphasis mine):

> When the `INSERT` statement to which the `UPSERT` is attached takes its values from a `SELECT` statement, there is a potential parsing ambiguity. The parser might not be able to tell if the `ON` keyword is introducing the `UPSERT` or if it is the `ON` clause of a join. To work around this, **the `SELECT` statement should always include a `WHERE` clause**, even if that `WHERE` clause is just `WHERE true`.

Comment: Thank you so much.